# How do I make it so a command only works if you're in a discord server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Let's say someone wants to use my bot in another server. I want to make it so the command only works if you are in my discord server. They can use it in the other server if they are in my discord server. If they are not, I don't want them to be able to use it.

I've tried many things such like `if (guild.member(USER_ID)` with no luck.

```
let guild2 = client.guilds.get('598974868779958282'),
  user_id = message.author.id;

if (guild2.member(user_id)) {
  message.author.send("you are in the support server!")
}else{

  message.author.send("you are not in the support server!")
}
```

I expected it to return the direct message "you are not in the support server!" because I am not in that guild but it always returns "you are in the support server" even if I'm not in the guild.

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(guild2.member(user_id))`? If it isn't `undefined`, the message author is indeed in the guild with the ID `598974868779958282`. Double check that the guild ID is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let guild2 = client.guilds.get('598974868779958282'),
  user_id = message.author.id;

if (guild2.members.has(user_id)) {
  message.author.send("you are in the support server!")
}else{

  message.author.send("you are not in the support server!")
}
```

The method `guild.member` doesn't exist try `guild.members` instead.